# Constructor allows to overwrite some variables of the class C#

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
class Item
{
    string reference;
    string name;
    double price;
    double tva;
}
```

I have a question: I'm trying to solve: write a constructor that allows to overwrite the reference and name during the instantiation.

Is this the right answer?

```
public Item(double priceHT, double RateTVA)
{
    Console.Write("Enter reference: ");
    reference = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    this.priceHT = priceHT;
    this.RateTVA = RateTVA;
}
```

Comment: Could be, but you shouldn't query for user inputs in a constructor.

Comment: can I write a contructor of only reference and name?

Comment: @bash.d I understand that it feels awkward, but I cant see why it can cause a problem?

Comment: Ideally your constructor would accept `string reference` and a `string name` parameters if you want to allow them to override them.

Comment: @bashrc In 99.99% of my cases I simply wouldn't do it. If you need to construct your objects using external input, use parameters. Also, your constructor becomes dependent on the console for constructing objects. I believe I never did this and probably will never do.

Comment: @bash.d yup. me neither. Makes code fragile. But code will still show well defined behavior in most cases. Not that I justify taking inputs in constructor.
Just trying to see if that can lead to an Undefined behavior in any way.

Comment: @bashrc I am more concernced about dependencies, but with computers everything is possible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public class Item {

   private string reference = string.Empty;
   private string name = string.Empty;
   private double price = 0.0;
   private double tva = 0.0;

   //initialize all properties
   public Item(string reference, string name, double price, double tva)
    {
        this.reference = reference;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.tva = tva
    }

    //use this one to only set reference and name
    public Item(string reference, string name)
    {
        this.reference = reference;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Using this pattern all of your members will be initialized properly and you overwrite `reference` and `name`. Don't know the whole purpose, though.